# GoDaddy forwarding while preserving structure of the content

Tags: godaddy, domain-forwarding

I have a domain, `handcrafted.codes`, managed through GoDaddy.  My host is through my local ISP, Suddenlink in this case.  What I would like to accomplish is straightforward: Point `handcrafted.codes` to `pages.suddenlink.net/physics`, preserving the folder structure of the content.  For example, a demo of the simple pendulum located at `pages.suddenlink.net/physics/amp/amp.htm` would be presented to the user as `handcrafted.codes/amp/amp.htm`.  Clean and informative.  (Apologies for not using the correct vocabulary.)

#### Research

I'm out of my depth with this subject, so there will be holes in my research.  The most relevant posts seem to be:

[GoDaddy URL forwarding while keeping relative path](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/godaddy-url-forwarding-while-keeping-relative-path)
This is fairly close to illustrating what I would like to do.

[Difference between forwarding and redirecting in GoDaddy?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54817/difference-between-forwarding-and-redirecting-in-godaddy)
Similar to the one above, but mentions wildcard paths.

#### Attempts

I've tried the most obvious things first (I hope).

*Forwarding without masking* simply redirects `handcrafted.codes` to `pages.suddenlink.net/physics`.  The user sees `pages.suddenlink.net/physics` in the address bar.  Okay, that's a start.

*Forwarding with masking* does the same thing, but the user is presented with a static `handcrafted.codes` in the address bar and static content in the title of the browser as dictated by the masking settings of the GoDaddy manager.

#### Question

Other reading I've done seems to suggest the use of `cname`.  Wildcard paths seem to make more intuitive sense to me.  Do these provide clues to this problem?  Any suggestions will be appreciated.